# Collect TypeProvider ProvidedMethod argument values in list

Tags: f#, type-providers, fsharp.data.typeproviders

Here is a simplified snippet of the Provided method which accepts variable number of arguments, in this case 3

```
ProvidedMethod(methodName = "GetContext", 
               parameters = [ for i in [ 1..3 ] do
                                  yield ProvidedParameter("Param" + string i, typeof<string>) ], 
               IsStaticMethod = true, returnType = typeof<string>, 
               InvokeCode = (fun args -> 
                   <@@ 
                       let dim1 : string = %%args.[0] : string
                       let dim2 : string = %%args.[1] : string
                       let dim3 : string = %%args.[2] : string
                 //    let dims = [for %%arg in args do yield (arg : string) ]// [1] error below
                 //    let dims = [for arg in args do yield (%%arg : string) ]// [2] error below
                       let dims = [ dim1; dim2; dim3 ] //this works
                       String.Join("--", dims)
                   @@>))
```

I want to collect all arguments in a single list.

What I've tried and did not work is commented in code quotation.

```
[1]: [FS0010] Unexpected prefix operator in expression
     [FS0594] Identifier expected

[2]: [FS0446] The variable 'arg' is bound in a quotation but is used as part of a spliced expression. This is not permitted since it may escape its scope.
```

Comment: A related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455091/f-type-provider-development-when-providing-a-method-how-to-access-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of solution also worked based on the answer suggested in comments: [F# Type Provider development: When providing a method, how to access parameters of variable number and type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455091/f-type-provider-development-when-providing-a-method-how-to-access-parameters)

```
ProvidedMethod(methodName = "GetContext", 
           parameters = [ for i in [ 1..3 ] do
                              yield ProvidedParameter("Param" + string i, typeof<string>) ], 
           IsStaticMethod = true, returnType = typeof<string>, 
           InvokeCode = (fun args -> 
               let dims = List.fold ( fun state e -> <@@ (%%string)::%%state @@>) <@@ []:List<string> @@> args
               <@@ 
                   String.Join("--", dims)
               @@>))
```

Answer (score 2):

Hacking your solution in the following way actually compiles

```
InvokeCode = (fun args -> 
    let dims: string[] = Array.zeroCreate args.Length
    let mutable i = 0
    let inc () = i <- i + 1
    <@@
        while i < args.Length do
            dims.[i] <- %%args.[i]
            inc ()
        String.Join("--", dims)
    @@>
```

But I suspect that you rather want to transform a `Quotations.Expr[]` of the shape `[|Value ("a"); Value ("b"); Value ("c")|]` into a single `Quotations.Expr`.

You can use the patterns in `Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns` to extract stuff from the expressions in the following way

```
InvokeCode = (fun args -> 
    let dims =
        args
        |> Array.choose (function | Value(value, _) -> value |> string |> Some | _ -> None)
        |> fun arr -> String.Join("--", arr)
    <@@ dims @@>
```